# Python making a file produces fatal error only on boot?

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a program that makes a batch file to put itself into the startup folder. This works when you manually launch the program but when its already in the "Startup" folder and it launches automatically on boot I get the following error:

```
Fatal Error: Python failed to execute the script
```

I narrowed it down to being the function that creates and writes to the batch file itself, although this function is useless when the program is already in the startup folder as I use an "if" statement to prevent that from happening.

Here is the code for the function:

```
def moveIO():
    move = open('moveIO.bat','w')
    move.write('move /Y "' + str(dirName) + '\\FPSBooster.exe" "' + str(targetPath) + '\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup"')
    move.close()
```

Here are the variables and the "if" statement that detects whether the program is already in the stratup folder:

```
dirName = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
targetPath = os.getenv('APPDATA')
if dirName != targetPath + '\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup':
moveIO()
```

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what is this supposed FPSBooster advertised to be doing?

Comment: It's a little program that spams the calculator app. Purely for practicing python and the os module :)

Comment: Thanks! That's an odd choice for a name, then. :)

Comment: Haha it is indeed, I wanted to try it out on one of my buddies as well, its not harmful and stops after a certain amount of time

Comment: I searched for the error you get and the top results are all related to packagers who pretend to turn scripts into `.exe`. You're not using any of those, are you?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using pyinstaller to turn it into an .exe. The main reason I did this was to get used to making exe files to run all my programs on computers that dont't have python installed.

Comment: Uhm ... well ... you should have mentioned that in the question! These programs don't actually create `.exe` out of scripts. It's just cheating. They unpack python, the script and other stuff into a temporary directory. A huge waste of time during startup. So the issue might be missing access rights for creating the files to run python to execute the script. Don't use pyinstaller and try again.

Comment: Aah! Yeah, that worked, thanks for the help, man. I understand how it works now, but does that mean there is no way to make it an .exe file? To me it seems kind of odd because that would mean anyone who wants to use my program (not necessarily this one) have to have python installed.

Comment: I'll write it as answer, if that's okay? That way you can close this. Regarding the rest: Well, if you give them an `.exe` they still got python with it as well, it`s just hidden. I don't see another way, except maybe trying `nuitka` which transpiles python to c code and then compiles it. I'll add that into my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as we found out, was hidden behind missing information.

OP used pyinstaller, which caused a whole lot of trouble. Removing that and running the script properly through python directly fixed the issue.

I'd like suggest trying `nuitka`, which convert scripts to C code, which then get compiled to `.exe` and thus avoids issues like missing access rights for creating temporary directories and dumping the python interpreter into it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! This has been bugging me for months!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
move = open("moveIO.bat", "w+")
```

w+ : Opens a file for both writing and reading. Overwrites the existing file if the file exists. If the file does not exist, creates a new file for reading and writing.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I can add the "if" statement and variables i use in the original post I'm using in case that might be the problem